# Infinispan @CacheEntryExpired listener - event firing twice

Tags: java, infinispan

I have a n implementation of CacheEntryExpired listener added via infinispan cache .addListener() method.

The listener event is fired on entry expiration. 
The problem is, that every time the event is fired twice.

I verified (using debugger and cache.getListeners()) that the cache does not contain two instances of the same Listener of mine. The result of getListeners is:

```
     (java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet<E>) [org.infinispan.iteration.impl.LocalEntryRetriever$PartitionListener@666SAT, my.supercool.package.MyExpirationEventListenerImpl@666TAN]
```

So there is only one listener. The listener implements the interface:

```
@Listener
public interface TokenExpirationEventListener<T> {

@CacheEntryExpired
   public void entryExpired(CacheEntryExpiredEvent<String, T> event);       
}
```

And an implementation looks like:

```
@Override
@CacheEntryExpired
public void entryExpired(CacheEntryExpiredEvent<String, T> event) {
    CODE
}
```

But removing @CacheEntryExpired and @Listener annotations from the interface (just trying) did not cause the event to occur only once.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, that I get TWO events on each entry expiration event?

The infinispan version is 8.2.0.final.

EDIT2:
I was able to track down all the configuration that is causing trouble. The code that will allow to reproduce the error is:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CacheMode;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ClusteringConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration;
import org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.configuration.global.TransportConfigurationBuilder;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.notifications.Listener;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.annotation.CacheEntryExpired;
import org.infinispan.notifications.cachelistener.event.CacheEntryExpiredEvent;

@Listener
public class TestMain { 

private Cache<String, String> cache;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TestMain().test();
}

private void test() throws Exception{
    configureInfinispan();

    cache.put("test", "test", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    cache.put("test2", "test", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);       
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(100);          
    }
}



public void configureInfinispan(){
    DefaultCacheManager defaultCacheManager = configureCachaManager();//globalConfigurationBuilder.build(), defaultConfigurationBuilder.build(), /*startNow*/ true)

    Configuration conf = defaultCacheManager.getDefaultCacheConfiguration();
    ConfigurationBuilder cacheConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().read(conf);
    cacheConfigBuilder.expiration().enableReaper().wakeUpInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //to speed test results


    duplicationReason2(cacheConfigBuilder);
    defaultCacheManager.defineConfiguration("testCache", cacheConfigBuilder.build());

    cache = defaultCacheManager.getCache("testCache");
    cache.addListener(new TestMain());
    System.out.println("conf");
}

public DefaultCacheManager configureCachaManager(){
    GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigurationBuilder = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder();
    ConfigurationBuilder defaultConfigurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    duplicationReason1(defaultConfigurationBuilder, globalConfigurationBuilder);

    return new DefaultCacheManager(globalConfigurationBuilder.build(), defaultConfigurationBuilder.build(), true);
}

@CacheEntryExpired
public void entryExpired(CacheEntryExpiredEvent<String, String> event) {
    System.out.println("Expired:" + event.getKey());
}

private void duplicationReason2(ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder) {
    configurationBuilder.persistence() //enable persistence
            .passivation(false)
            .addSingleFileStore()
            .location("C:/test/infinispan")
            // Disable writing anything to the file except when we do shutdown
            .maxEntries(0)
            .shared(false)
            .fetchPersistentState(true)
            .async() //write-behind
            .enable() //write-behind
            .threadPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) //writing threads
            .preload(true); //load data from file on startup
}

private void duplicationReason1(ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigurationBuilder){
    configureCacheOperationalMode(configurationBuilder);
    configureTransport(globalConfigurationBuilder);
}

private void configureCacheOperationalMode(ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder) {
    ClusteringConfigurationBuilder clusteringConfigurationBuilder = configurationBuilder.clustering();
    clusteringConfigurationBuilder.cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC);
}

private void configureTransport(GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigurationBuilder) {
    TransportConfigurationBuilder transportConfigurationBuilder = globalConfigurationBuilder.transport().defaultTransport();
    transportConfigurationBuilder.addProperty("configurationFile", "default-configs/default-jgroups-udp.xml");
}
```

}

Running this will (unfortunatelly you need to kill the main thread youself afterwards) cause the event to be printed twice.

There are two methods that together cause this. commenting one  of them and leaving the second causes the event to fire once.

The methods are named duplicationReason1 and duplicationReason2.

Maybe there is something I do not understand in the configuration?

Comment: What version are you using? Can you share your configuration? I've just tried Infinispan 9.0.0-SNAPSHOT with local cache and the listener was called only once.

Comment: @JakubMarkos the version is 8.2.0.Final (but was 8.1.2.Final, I just notice that last week a release appeared). I've edited the post with the configuration.....

Comment: @maslan Are you able to just post a small code snippet that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Mudokonman Im trying hard to track down everthing that happend to cache manager and cache config in a large app to reproduce it in a copy-pasteable mini app to paste here :)

Comment: @JakubMarkos

I was able to create a simple class to reproduce the problem. Maybe I dont get something from the configuration stuff?

I can add a pom.xml if You need it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I was able to see what is going on with the test case you added, thanks!

This is a bug in clustered caches atm.  I logged [1] to look into it, you should follow if you want updates.

While we can fix the duplicate issue, you will still have other possible occurrences of duplicates so you should still be able to handle them.  An example of when a duplicate is generated can be found at [2] under "Concurrent expiration access".  Thus you should normally just ignore expiration events that have a null value.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-6405
[2] http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/10/expiration-enhancements.html

Comment: Hi!
According to the javadoc, when this event happens, the value can be sometimes null sometimes not, can I be sure, that one of the events will only have null value and one will not? 

Thanks for the reply, I will look into [2] :)

Comment: @maslan The documented null value will only occur if a corresponding non null is also raised just before it.  The case you found here does the same thing if you print out the entire event and not just the key.

Comment: Also to note that if an entry only expires from the store, if it doesn't implement the AdvancedCacheExpirationWriter interface you will only receive the key and not a value.  So it is valid to receive notifications with null values.  This is because it might be prohibitively expensive to load the values for expired entries.

Comment: Ok, so can You please tell me if I got it. I need to get only one expiration event per expired key, and I actually need the value. So
1.I should ignore events with null value. But can I be sure that each expiration event will have at least one call to eventExpired with a non-null value or to be sure I need to have that interface implemented?

2 If I make sure my objects implement this interface, is there some additional memory/CPU cost related to doing this?

Comment: @maslan The interface I mentioned is for a CacheWriter which is a back end store, see http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_persistence.  Unfortunately most stores don't return the value since it is costly to do so.  If you aren't using a store then your expiration will always have a non null value unless it is a duplicate.  If you have a store and an entry expires from there it will not have the value unless the store implements the interface I mentioned.  There is no additional cost for the store when implementing this.